# Gumstix, caspa camera and Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ros, gumstix, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there any previous work done with this combination? Ubuntu on Gumstix is running (GNU/Linux 2.6.36 armv7l). Also would the ROS [ucv_camera](http://ros.org/wiki/uvc_camera) package be useful for camera access or maybe there are some other better options?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27556/gumstix,-caspa-camera-and-ubuntu-11.04/) by [ajr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/1453/ajr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2012-02-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 11.04 can be made to work with Gumstix Caspa camera by using Angstrom kernel 2.6.34. I build rootfs /dev/sdb2 part of SD card by using rootstock utility following these instructions:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/gumros/ubuntu

And for /dev/sdb1 I used Caspa camera compatible set of uImage, u-boot and MLO. Make sure you have mt9v032.ko driver at /lib/modules/2.6.34/kernel/drivers/media/video folder.
[Good third party webpage for overall info related gumstix](http://homepages.laas.fr/bvandepo/wiki/doku.php?id=gumstixthomas#a-z_incorporate_the_kernel_with_mt9v032_caspapx_camera_driver)

Usable command to check which modules you have installed in kernel is lsmod.

---

Originally posted by [ajr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/1453/ajr_/) with karma: 97 on 2012-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1